# Cucumber js how to provide shared step definitions

Tags: node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm creating my own tests using Cucumber-js and now I find myself with some step definition that I could reuse.
More specifically, I wanted to create a package with my common steps and then include the library into the different test suites.
I was playing around with

```
module.exports = function () {
   this.Given(`I'm standard`, function(done) {
   })
}
```

but when I use require() in the test suite it doesn't find the steps.

I was looking around but I couldn't find any documentation around this. Is  this some bad practice? and If so, how I can avoid to repeat exactly the same code in different test suite packages?

Comment: Just add a common directory outside of the suites and add that to your profile

Comment: can you expand the suggestion a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `_shared.spec.ts` file within the folder of your tests and cucumber.js is gonna find directly the shared definition to reuse.